# iterating over two lists to create a new list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate over two lists to populate a new list with the outcome, but am not sure where it's going wrong. Note: i'm a beginner using Python. Mahalo in advance!

```
sumList = [27400.0, 32900.0, 42200.0, 40600.0];
volList = [27000.0, 40000.0, 31000.0, 40000.0];
rendeList = [];

x = 0;
for sumValue in range (0, len(sumList)-1):
    rendeList = rendeList.append((sumList[x]/volList[x])*100)
    x += 1;
```

However, I get an Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. After running the for loop, i get:

```
print rendeList
None
```

My expected outcome would have been:

```
print rendeList
[101.48, 82.25, 136.13, 101.49]
```

Comment: assigning the return value of append is the error. It appends in place. And return's `none`

Comment: Not related to your particular question, but you might like to know that you can do just `for sumValue in sumList`.  Further, you might find the `enumerate` function useful.  you can do `for x, sumValue in enumerate(sumList)`

Comment: @CoupleWavyLines : why stop at `enumerate` when there is `zip`?

Comment: @njzk2 You're right! That's much better for this problem. Oh well, I'm still glad to mention enumerate to a beginner. I wrote way too much `x=0`...`x+=1` in my first months of Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list.append(x)` modifies the list and returns `None`.
Change your code to:

```
for sumValue in range (0, len(sumList)):
    rendeList.append((sumList[x]/volList[x])*100)
    x += 1
```

Or simplify it to:

```
for sumValue, volValue in zip(sumList, volList):
    rendeList.append((sumValue / volValue) * 100)
```

Comment: Given the expected outcome in the question, I think the '-1' in `len(sumList)-1` in the question and this answer are an error.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your solution using list comprehension:

```
 result = [a[0]/a[1]*100 for a in zip(sumList, volList)]
```

Comment: `result = [s / v * 100 for s, v in zip(sumList, volList)]`

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that `list.append` returns `None`

```
>>> a_list = list('abc')
>>> print(a_list.append('d'))
None
>>> a_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

And if you reassign a_list:

```
>>> a_list = a_list.append('e')
>>> a_list
>>> print(a_list)
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's `map` function would be perfect for this:

```
rendeList = map(lambda x,y: x/y*100, sumList, volList)
```

The `map` function returns a list where a function (the first argument, which here I've supplied as a [Lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)) is applied to each element of the passed in list, or in this case each pair of elements from the two lists passed in.